# Remove duplicates in a php loop - only addup values from unique ID #

Tags: php

Ive seen many posts explaining to use `array_unique` but i dont think that will work with my scenario...

I have multiple results in this report, if you notice from my picture the ST/OT has duplicate `1.50` and `2.00` values because each sql entry has `1.50` and `2.00` for each st_ot cell

At the bottom where it totals up, obviously now from `$stot_total += $data["stot"];`. It is adding up the total. But what I really want is the total of `1.50 + 2.00 (3.50)`. I dont want it to add the duplicates.

All the ones that are `1.50` have the same `ID#` as well, so if theres a way to only add values from `ID#1`, then `ID#2`, then `ID#3` and so on... that would work for me...

i apologize for this horrible post... this question is regarding the ST/OT values only **

```
foreach($dary as $data){
$stot_total += $data["stot"];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show content of `$dary` variable (by `var_dump` or `print_r`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple modification of the answer from @awei should do the trick for you:

```
<?php
$stot_bucket = array();

foreach($dary as $data)
{
    // Since you don't need to access the values in a multi-dimensional way, just combine the two keys into one to make the final summing simpler
    $stot_bucket[$data["id"] . $data["stot"]] = $data["stot"];
}

$stot_total = array_sum($stot_bucket);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
     $stot_bucket = array();
     
     foreach ($records as $record) {
          // do your normal rendering of all the rows
          $stot_bucket[] = $record['stot'];
     }
     
     $stot_total = array_sum(array_unique($stot_bucket));
?>
```

reference: [array_unique docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 i.e. when the string representation is the same, the first element will be used.
```

Comment: this kinda works... but i need it to grab values from unique id# $data["id"];  because if i have more rows below that are 2.00 but from a different ID# i want those 2.00 added aswell to the total

Comment: so, just to fully understand, you need to add where the stot is unique with respect to its respective id? do you have an example?